# How to generate combination of fix length strings using a set of characters?

Tags: python, python-itertools

In Python, how can I generate a string with all combinations of a set of characters up to a certain length?

I know how to use itertools to generate all combinations and permutations, but I can't figure out how to generate strings of dynamic length.

For example:

a = [0,1]
length = 4

Result:

[0000,
0001,
0010,
0011,
0100,
0101,
0110,
0111,
1000,
1001,
1101,
1110,
1111]

Comment: You asked for strings "up to a certain length", but in your example, you only give the results with exactly that length.

Comment: That's a good point. I was going to loop a function with range() once  I figured out how to generate results of fixed length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `itertools.product`:

```
li = []
for i in itertools.product([0,1], repeat=4):
    li.append(''.join(map(str, i)))
print (li)

>>> li
['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
```

Possible one liner:

```
[''.join(map(str, i)) for i in itertools.product([0,1], repeat=4)]
```

Comment: Thank you. That shall teach me to read through the doc more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

use `product` from itertools module.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [i for i in product([0,1],repeat=4)]
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```